# How to solve 'module' object is not iterable in django

Tags: python, django

I have created a Django application and initially the code worked perfectly but when I restarted the development server I started having 'module' object not iterable exception. This is my code

views.py

```
import datetime
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import render
from forms.forms import *
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.http import HttpResponse
from patients.models import *


def doctor_view(request, id):
    patients = Patients.objects.get(id=id)
     if request.method == "POST":
            form = DoctorForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                f = form.save(commit=False)
                date = datetime.datetime.now()
                f.date_seen = date
                f.save()
                messages.info(request, 'patient profile was successfully updated !!!')
        else:

            form = DoctorForm(instance=patients)
            date = datetime.datetime.now()
        return render(request, 'doctors/templates/patient_registration.html',
                      {'form': form, 'title': 'Patient Treatment', 'patients': patients, 'date': date, 'messages': messages})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:id>/', views.doctor_view, name='doctor-views'),
  
]
```

Traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /doctor/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\DAS_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\DAS_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\DAS_project\doctors\views.py", line 42, in doctor_view
    {'form': form, 'title': 'Patient Treatment', 'patients': patients, 'date': date, 'messages': messages})
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\DAS_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\DAS_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\DAS_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\DAS_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\DAS_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\DAS_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\DAS_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\DAS_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\DAS_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\DAS_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\DAS_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\DAS_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\DAS_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\DAS_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\SERU\Desktop\School Projects\DAS_project\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 167, in render
    values = list(values)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable
```

I am passing the values to the template using a dictionary and my html template is as follows. I have also installed `django-crispy-forms`.

````html
{% extends 'patients/templates/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 d-flex flex-column" style="margin-lef:auto; align-items:center; justify-content:center">
           <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
               <h4 class="mt-3 mb-2">Patient Treatment</h4>
               <hr class="my-4">
           </div>
            <div class="col-8 d-flex" style="border:1px solid #dfdfdf;z-index:20;color:maroon">
                <h1 class="lead" style="margin:20px;">Treating: </h1>
                <h6 class=" lead " style="margin:20px;" >Name:   {{ patients.name}}</h6> <h6 class=" lead " style="margin-top:20px;" >{{ patients.surname}}</h6>
                <h6 class=" lead " style="margin:20px;" >Nat ID:    {{ patients.id_no}}</h6> <h6 class=" lead " style="margin-top:20px;" >Gender:    {{ patients.gender}}</h6>
                 {% for message in messages %}
                <div  class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}" role="alert" style="color:#0e466b;;"> {{ message }}</div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                {{ form.symptoms|as_crispy_field }}
           </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                {{ form.disease|as_crispy_field }}
           </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                {{ form.treatment|as_crispy_field }}
           </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-">
                 <input type="submit" value="Send to Doctor" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                 <a href="email" class="btn btn-info btn-sm ml-3">Send email</a>
                 <hr class="my-4">
                <center> <h6 class="  " style="margin:20px;" >  {{ date}}</h6></center>
            </div>
    </div>

  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->


  <!-- The Modal -->

    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}```
````

Comment: Looks like it might be a template issue. Can you share your template?

Comment: I have added the template code on the question

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your context dictionary. Django automatically adds a `messages` object to the request context without you needing to add it manually (assuming you have `MessageMiddleware` enabled). What you're doing at the end of your dictionary is overriding that object with the module `messages` that you imported at the top of your file.

Simply removing the key-value pair `'messages': messages` from your dictionary should fix the issue.

```
# ...
return render(request, 'doctors/templates/patient_registration.html',
                      {'form': form, 'title': 'Patient Treatment', 'patients': patients, 'date': date})
```